# Better way to go up/down slope based on yaw?

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

Alright, so I got a bit of movement code and I'm thinking I'm going to need to manually input when to go up/down a slope. All I got to work with is the slope's normal, and vector, and My current and previous position, and my yaw.

Is there a better way to rotate whether I go up or down the slope based on my yaw?

```
Vector3f move = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
        move.x = (float)-Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw));
        move.z = (float)-Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw));

        System.out.println("slopeNormal.z: " + slopeNormal.z + "move.z: " + move.z);

        move.normalise();

        float vx = (float) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(move.y, 2) + Math.pow(move.z, 2)) * move.x);
        float vy = (float) (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(move.x, 2) + Math.pow(move.z, 2)) * move.y);
        float vz = - vx * slopeNormal.x - vy * slopeNormal.y;
        move.scale(movementSpeed * delta); 

        if(vz < 0)
            move.y -= slopeVec.y * 1.5f;

        if(vz > 0)
            move.y += slopeVec.y * 1.5f;

        Vector3f.add(pos, move, pos);
```

Edit: updated code.

Comment: You can get more answers on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, the game development brother of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the following is incorrect:

```
move.x = (float)-Math.toDegrees(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw)));
move.z = (float)-Math.toDegrees(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw)));
```

`Math.toDegrees` converts an angle in radians to one in degrees, but the results of `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` are not angles.

Assume zero yaw is in the positive x-direction... and define vx, vy, vz = rate of motion along 3 axes, s = speed, and slope normal = nx, ny, nz where nx^2 + ny^2 + nz^2 = 1.  So nx = ny = 0, nz = 1 would be flat.

First, I define x', y' = axes relative to the flat ground (motion is constrained to ground).  Then (the following is not valid Java, but I'm enclosing it in code format anyway):

```
vx' = cos(yaw) * s
vy' = sin(yaw) * s
```

Then I need to rotate from x', y' coordinates to real-world coordinates.  That is done using the slope normal:

```
vx = sqrt(vy^2 + vz^2) vx'
vy = sqrt(vx^2 + vz^2) vy'
vz = - vx' nx - vy' ny
```

A check on this transformation: vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2 must equal vx'^2 + vy'^2 = s^2.  I think this works out.

So to answer your question: up or down?    vz > 0 is up, vz < 0 is down.

Comment: Alright, I edited my code in the question. Do I have the code right? Also thanks for the ToDegrees catch. :3